# Unique ID CSS | Why is my styling being picked up elsewhere?

Tags: css

A tricky one here.

I have styling for two UL's on a page which both contain anchors.

Each of the UL's have their own specific ID and specific styling which is all correct.

Here is the confusing part - say I have this:

```
#nav {
    margin: 20px 0 0 0;
  }
    #nav li {
      float: left;

    }
      #nav li a {
        display: block;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        color: #555454;
        font-size: 14px;
        padding: 11px 17px;

      }
```

And then this:

```
#gt-list 
    {
        margin: 10px 0 0 0;
    }
        #gt-list li, a
        {
            color: #fff;
            margin: 0 0 10px 0;
        }
            #gt-list li a:hover 
            {
                color: #ff6b00;
            }
        #gt-list li img 
        {
            float: left;
            margin: 0 15px 0 0;
            width: 20px;
        }
        #gt-list li span
        {
            float: left;
            display: inline-block;
            margin: 2px 0 0 0;

        }
```

Here is HTML to go with:

```
<ul id="nav">
                    <li class="selected">
                        <a href="#">
                            Home
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            About us
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            Ways to give
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            Our Work
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            News
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            Learn
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            Contact Us
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
```

The above is actual styling used on a site.

So here is my issue: the #nav is picking up the LI styling from #gt-list along with anchor styling.

I have inserted all parent div ID's to each UL and this had no affect.

I don't understand this!?!?

Comment: It sounds like the `#nav` list items are included within the `#gt-list` items. Try using a child selector for the `#gt-list > li` ([ref](http://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The culprit is:

```
#gt-list li, a
    {
        color: #fff;
        margin: 0 0 10px 0;
    }
```

The comma between `li` and `a` causes the styles specified to be applied to `a` globally as it denotes:
*All `li` within #gt-list AND all `a`*.
Whereas what you want it to read is:
*All `li` AND `a` within #gt-list*

Change it to

```
#gt-list li a
    {
        color: #fff;
        margin: 0 0 10px 0;
    }
```

Comment: This is it - thank you! How annoying though... I have to write a new line JUST to add the same styling for the anchor... zzzz

Comment: @Filth - you might want to learn about [CSS Preprocessors](http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/css-preprocessors/) like SASS, LESS, etc. and if you are using visual studio, then try [Web Workbench](http://www.mindscapehq.com/products/web-workbench)

Answer (score 3):

This rule has a comma in it, which means it will be applied to all `li` elements under the one with that id AND all anchor elements, regardless of where they are.

```css
    #gt-list li, a
```

Comment: This is it - thank you! How annoying though... I have to write a new line JUST to add the same styling for the anchor... zzzz